# how can i recognise and check selected option in uipickerview from the content of the textfield related to that uipickerview

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

My problem is that when i try to recognise the content of the textfield of uipickerview and i try to check option which content is equal to content of textfield, if options are more than three options and selected option is the fourth or after the checkmark is not created and nothing is checked.
i made a pickercell class( a uiview contain checkmark)  to determine which option is selected. in the class which implement delegates of uipickerview and generate the ui, i made this to check selected option :

```
for (int i = 0; i < [self.customPickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:0]; i++)
{
    PickerViewCell *label = (PickerViewCell *)[self.customPickerView viewForRow:i forComponent:0];
    for (int j = 0; j < [self.selectedItems count]; j++) {
        if ([(NSString *)[self.selectedItems objectAtIndex:j]
             isEqualToString:(NSString *)[self.options objectAtIndex:i]]) {
            label.checkMarkView.hidden = NO;
        }
    }    
}
```

and in pickerview delegate i made this :

```
PickerViewCell *label = (PickerViewCell *)view;
    self.customPickerView.showsSelectionIndicator   = NO;
    // Add a gesture recognizer to detect taps in pickerview
    UITapGestureRecognizer *MultipleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]
                                            initWithTarget:self
                                                    action:@selector(tapMultipleInPickerView:)];
    [MultipleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
    //[singleTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    [self.customPickerView addGestureRecognizer:MultipleTap];
    if (!label)
    {
        // Customize your label (or any other type UIView) here
        label = [[PickerViewCell alloc]
                 initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.customPickerView.bounds.size.width * 0.8, 44.0f)];
    }
    if (row < [self.options count])
    {
        label.label.text = (NSString *)[self.options objectAtIndex:row];
        //label.checkMarkView.hidden = !(row == self.currentOption);
    }
    return label;
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Have you solved this issue?

Comment: Non not yet !!! any help will be appreciated

Comment: can you post a more complete code of the UIViewController that contains this picker view?